# Linux C timer - signal disrupts current process

Tags: c, signals

I'm working on a application that has specific timing restraints such that an event should occur (ideally exactly) every 200us.  I'm trying to do this with a timer and signal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

timer_t timer_id;

void start_timer(void)
{
    struct itimerspec value;

    value.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_value.tv_nsec = 20000;

    value.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 200000;

    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &timer_id);
    timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &value, NULL);
}

void handler(int sig) {
     printf("in handler\n");
}

void *my_thread(void *ignore)
{
    (void)ignore;

    start_timer();
    // Sleep forever
    while(1) sleep(1000);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;

    (void) signal(SIGALRM, handler);
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, my_thread, NULL);
    // sleep is a placeholder for this SO question.  I want to do 
    // other processing here
    sleep(5000);
    printf("sleep finished\n");
}
```

After 200us the signal handler is called.  It appears to be called when the sleep(5000) line is running because the "sleep finished" message is displayed early.  I want the timer to disrupt the thread that started the timer, not the main process.  This is why I created a thread to start it.  Is there a way to have the signal only abort the current instruction on the thread instead of on the main process?  I know that the other threads/processes will be blocked when the handler runs, but I wanted them to continue afterwards as if nothing happened.  For example, in this case I want to sleep at least 5000 seconds.

Comment: Which line is being printed first?

Comment: Undefined behavior for calling a non async-safe function in a signal handler.

Comment: @TonyTannous "in handler" is displayed first.

Comment: @EOF: It's not actually UB unless the signal handler has interrupted a non-AS-safe function, which shouldn't be the case (and wouldn't if OP masked signals properly).

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It's also undefined behavior if any non-lockfree atomic or `volatile sig_atomic_t` object is read in signal handler context when it was last written in non-signal-handler context, and vice versa. You *really* cannot use non async-safe functions in signal handlers safely.

Comment: @EOF: The handler isn't doing that.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE `printf()` *is* doing that.

Comment: @EOF: No, `printf` is part of the language. If it's implemented that way, it must be done in such a manner that it adheres to the behavior as specified, which (under POSIX) allows calling it from a signal handler as long as it did not interrupt an AS-unsafe function. You can't reason about standard functons in terms of how you presume they must be implemented, only in terms of how they're specified.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE citation needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can block the signal (`pthread_sigmask`) in the main thread before starting any other threads, and only unblock it in the thread intended to handle it. This will ensure that it arrives in the thread you want it in.

However, if you already have threads, are you sure you actually need a timer generating a signal for this? `clock_nanosleep` should allow sleep with wakeup at a precise time, and avoids all the awfulness of signals.

Comment: Thanks, clock_nanosleep is exactly what I'm looking for.  I was previously using nanosleep but keep running into issue with clock drift.